Is it true $\sup_{x\in \overline{D}}||Tx||=\sup_{x\in \overline{D}\setminus D}||Tx||$?
Let $X$ and $Y$ be two Banach spaces and let $T\in L(X, Y)$, where $L(X, Y)$ is the set of all bounded linear operators from $X$ to $Y$. Assume that $D$ is a bounded subset of $X$. $\overline{D}$ denotes the closure of $D$ and $\overline{D}\setminus D$ denotes the set of all limit points of $D$. We assume that $\overline{D}\setminus D\ne\phi$. Then can we conclude that $$\sup_{x\in \overline{D}}||Tx||=\sup_{x\in \overline{D}\setminus D}||Tx||~~~~?$$
We know that $\sup_{x\in \overline{D}}||Tx||=\sup_{x\in D}||Tx||$. But I am not able to come to a conclusion after this. Please help me. Any help is appreciated. If the assertion is wrong then give an example.

This equality possibly fails when there is significant difference in behavior of the operator $T$ between points inside $D$ and on the boundary $\overline{D} \setminus D$. Specifically if the operator $T$ dampens or annihilates the vectors on the boundary compared to those inside $D$, the supremum over $\overline{D} \setminus D$ will be strictly less than the supremum over $\overline{D}$. This can happen if $T$ is defined such that it acts trivially on boundary points while behaving non-trivially on the interior of $D$. However, this much is just speculation to why it may possibly not hold.

Thank you for a detailed explanation. Is it wrong that if a bounded linear operator attains its supremum over $D$ then it must attain at the boundary of $D$? When can we expect such things?

If a bounded linear operator attains its supremum over $D$, it doesn't always attain it at the boundary of $D$ - this depends on the compactness of $D$ (i.e. closed and bounded in finite-dimensional spaces). If $D$ is compact, then by the extreme value theorem any continuous function on $D$ will attain its supremum somewhere on $D$. If $D$ is compact and $T$ is continuous, there is no guarantee that it must be on the boundary. Similarly for if $D$ is not compact.

Furthermore, if $T$ diminishes or is trivial at the boundary, the supremum will typically be inside $D$. Conversely, if $T$ attains larger norms at the boundary then the supremum is typically there.

To summarise, basically we can expect the supremum at the boundary if $D$ is an open or unbounded set, if $T$ behaves more 'strongly' near the boundary and if $T$ is continuous but $D$ is not compact. Feel free to reach out for any help.

Thank you for the detailed answer. The more you provide detailed answers the more I can understand. I am a beginner in these topics.

A bounded set in a normed linear space need not have any limit points. For example, an orthonormal sequence in  a Hilbert space has no limit points. In such case your RHS is $0$.

If the bounded set has a limit point then what can we conclude?

No, unless $D$ has 'enough' limit points the equation is not true.

Many thanks for your answer. I have edited the question by taking the set of limit points as non-empty. If possible, can you please elaborate on the cases where it has plenty number of limit points and the instances when it does not?

If you just ${x, x/2,/x/3,...}$ to an orthonormal basis where $x$ is a fixed non zero vector, you cannot expect the equation to be true even though $0$ is now a limit point.  If $D$ is a disk, the the equation does hold.

As mentioned in the comments, it is important to note that if $D$ is open and bounded the results holds (I can add a proof for this if necessary). On the other side, if $D$ is closed, then $\overline{D}\backslash D=\emptyset$, so it doesn't follow one of your hypothesis.
It follows from the latter that in order to find a proper counter-example we will need a neither open nor closed set. Fortunately one can build such a counter-example in a very easy way by considering $T:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined by $T(x)=x$ and $D=(0,1]$. In such a case, $\overline{D}=[0,1]$ and $\overline{D}\backslash D=\{0\}$, so
$$ \sup_{x\in \overline{D}} ||Tx|| = \sup_{x\in [0,1]} |x|=1, $$
but
$$ \sup_{x\in\overline{D}\backslash D} ||Tx|| = \sup_{x\in\{0\}}|x|=0. $$
